# deploy same war file twice as different paths in tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I have a war file from an Eclipse+Maven webapp/Jersey Service project, i.e., myapp.war.  manually deploy it in webapp folder works just fine. the uri would be http://mydomain/myapp

I would like to create/deploy the same myapp.war as another app in the same tomcat, I thought by renaming it to myapp2.war and drop it into webapps folder would work, but it doesn't.

I also just copied webapps/myapp to webapps/myapp2.  That doesn't work either.

Am I missing something?  What is the easiest way to achieve my purpose, i.e., recreate the 2nd maven project from the original maven project?

**Update:
If I un-deploy the original, myapp, then restart tomcat, myapp1 works.  There seem to be some interference, and the first one wins?**

Comment: check if your war file contains a file called context.xml: That might define the context name, rather than the war file name.

Comment: @Sean When you rename the 2 war, is the war being exploded? And when you go to it do you get 404 errors?

Comment: there is no context.xml

Comment: I do see myapp2 folder gets created with all the files, and Yes, I get 404.

Comment: Any solution on this? Even if I build the second war file in a different name, i get javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException for my beans.

Answer (score 0):

The tomcat error log showed the 2nd web app failed to load due to a native lib only allow to be loaded once:

Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library xxx already loaded in another classloader

Answer (score 0):

Issue occurs when both war files have same value for webAppRootKey in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml`. Change the following entry in the second war file:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
  <param-value>myproject-v2.webapp.root</param-value>
</context-param>
```

For future reference, add this entry in `src/main/resources/logging.properties` so it'll show exact error (in case above issue, it says another war with that entry already exists)

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].level=INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```